# How to create Element and Attriubte from different tables in Sql Server XML?

Tags: xml, sql-server-2012

I am trying to use Sql Server 2012 Express to create some XML out of values in tables. Specifically, I want an element to have an attribute that comes from 1 table, and that same element to have a value that comes from another table. The use case is that the attribute represents an internal Id, while the value/text will represent something human readable.

I have 2 tables:

Card, which contains columns

```
Id, Name, BookId, and Page
```

Category, which contains columns

```
Id and Name
```

The desired XML is:

```
<Card id="2">
  <Name>My Card</Name>
  <Location>
    <Book cid="66">My Book</Book>
    <Page>118</Page>
  </Location>
</Card>
```

Note the "Book" element, which has an attribute from Card table and Value/Text from Category table.

I have tried 2 queries that get me pretty close, but not quite there. This query will put the book id in the "Location" element (boo!), but it structures the element the way I want (yay!):

```
select
    c.Id [@id],
    c.Name,
    (
        select
            (
                select
                    c.BookId [@cid]
                    ,book.Name
                for
                    xml path( 'Book' ), type
            ),
            c.[Page]
        for
            xml path( 'Location' ), type
    )
from
     Card c
     left outer join Category book on book.Id = c.BookId
where
    c.Id = @cardId
for
    xml path( 'Card' ), type
```

produces

```
<Card id="2">
  <Name>My Card</Name>
  <Location>
    <Book cid="66">
      <Name>My Book</Name> <!-- need to stop My Book from appearing in its own element -->
    </Book>
    <Page>118</Page>
  </Location>
</Card>
```

and this query, which puts the book Id in the book element (yay!), but puts the book name in its own element (boo!).

```
select
        c.Id [@id],
        c.Name,
        (
            select
                c.BookId [@bookId],
                book.Name Book,
                c.[Page]
            for
                xml path( 'Location' ), type
        )
    from
         Card c
         left outer join Category book on book.Id = c.BookId
    where
        c.Id = @cardId
    for
        xml path( 'Card' ), type
```

which produces

```
<Card id="2">
  <Name>My Card</Name>
  <Location bookId="66"> <!-- need bookId to appear in the Book element -->
    <Book>My Book</Book>
    <Page>118</Page>
  </Location>
</Card>
```

I think I'm pretty close, but at this point it's blind trial and error, and that is just not how I want to spend my holiday :) Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT - 2017/01/08
I finally ended up with the following query, which provided exactly what I wanted. Shnugo has also provided a very similar answer below, without using the sub-select.

```
select
    c.Id [@id],
    c.Name,
    (
        select
            c.BookId [Book/@bookId],
            book.Name [Book],
            c.Page [Page]
        for
            xml path( 'Location' ), type
    )
from
    Card c
    inner join Category book on book.Id = c.BookId
for
    xml path( 'Card' ), type
```

Comment: I am sorry I have been away from this for a long time! Yes, I did manage to figure out how to solve it. I will look it up and post the answer, and if the answer is the same as one of these others I will mark it.

So sorry for delay!!!

Comment: Thanks again Shnugo. I am an awful procrastinator, but I have marked your answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is this you are looking for:

If there is no 1:n relation between `<Card>` and `<Location>`, there's no need for a sub-select...

```
DECLARE @Card TABLE(Id INT, Name VARCHAR(100), BookId INT,  [Page] INT);
INSERT INTO @Card VALUES(2,'My Card',66,118);
DECLARE @Category TABLE(Id INT,Name VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @Category VALUES(66,'My Book');

SELECT c.Id AS [@id]
      ,c.Name AS [Name]
      ,c.BookId AS [Location/Book/@cid]
      ,book.Name AS [Location/Book]
      ,c.Page AS [Location/Page]
from
     @Card c
     left outer join @Category book on book.Id = c.BookId
FOR XML PATH('Card')
```

The result

```
<Card id="2">
  <Name>My Card</Name>
  <Location>
    <Book cid="66">My Book</Book>
    <Page>118</Page>
  </Location>
</Card>
```

Comment: Sorry this took so long to answer, but yes, this is what I did, I used "select c.BookId [Book/@bookId]". I DID use a sub-element for location overall, but you are correct, I did not need to.

Comment: @emery.noel, no problem :-) Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with XQuery

```
select (

    select c.Id [@id], c.Name, book.Name [Book], book.Id [cid], c.Page
    from Card c
    left outer join Category book on book.Id = c.BookId
    where c.Id = @cardId
    for xml path('Card'), type

).query('

<Card id="{/Card/@id}">
    {/Card/Name}
    <Location>
        <Book cid="{/Card/cid}">{data(/Card/Book)}</Book>
        {/Card/Page}
    </Location>
</Card>

')
```

Comment: There's no need for this... `FOR XML PATH` allows you to define nested elements just by naming them as `[XPath]`

Comment: @Shnugo - Yes, thank you, I already saw your answer. Now I know it.